# Python command line argument with args.parse argument form list doesnt work

Tags: python, list, colors, command-line-arguments, args

Hi there I'm just starting to learn python. I have a problem with a program i want to modify called LineGenerator.py from the Mag Pi issue 7.
Full code:

http://www.themagpi.com/issue/issue-7/

This program introduces the command line arguments.

I am trying to add a command line argument to change the color of a graphic.

first i defined the colors:
...

```
WH = 255,255,255

RE = 255,0,0
```

and so on...

then i defined the command line argument:
...

```
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store', dest='colour', type=str, 
                    help='Choose Colour')
```

...

later in my program i want to draw the line
...

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, args.colour,(nSX),(nSY),(nEX,nEY),1)
```

...

When I start the script with

```
python LineGenerator.py -c WH
```

I get this Error message:

```
TypeError: invalid color argument
```

When i change the "args.colour" directly in the Code with "WH" then it works.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: parser.add_argument(-c, action='store'**.** dest='colour', type=str, 
                    help='Choose Colour') _Really dot after 'store'?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store your color values by name:

```
colors = { "WH": (255, 255, 255),
           "RE": (255, 0, 0),
         }
```

Then access the correct color using the string passed to the `-c` option:

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, colors[args.colour], (nSX), (nSY), (nEX,nEY), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `-c` as a string. Wrap it in quotes:

```
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store', dest='colour', type=str, 
                    help='Choose Colour')
```

Otherwise python will pass the value of the variable `-c`, whatever it is. Hope it helps!

Edit: Oh, that wasn't the problem... hahaha

Well, i figured out what it is anyway. When you're passing `WH` as an argument to the script, you are *not* passing the value of the variable `WH` - which is `255, 255, 255` - but instead you're passing the string literal `"WH"` as the argument to `draw.line`. Hence the error.

To fix this, you should specify the parameter `nargs`, and discard the `type` parameter, since the latter isn't needed:

```
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store', dest='colour', nargs=3,
                    help='Choose Colour')
...
colours = (int(i) for i in args.colours)
pygame.draw.line(screen, *colours,(nSX),(nSY),(nEX,nEY),1)
```

And when you're running it:

```
python LineGenerator.py -c 255, 255, 255
```

That's all! Hope it helps!

Comment: Updated with a proper answer for your problem. Check it out :)